# FileNotFoundException when creating new Thread in java

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I've an already works code to read an excel file. At first, the API in the controller clase receive the file as MultipartFile type. Then, because of some reasons, I need to convert the MultipartFile into File type. Here is the code:

```
private static File convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    try {
        File convertedFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        convertedFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convertedFile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return convertedFile;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IOException("Error in converting the file with error message: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here is the service class which called in the controller, which call the convert method above:

```
public void create(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    try {
        File newFile = convert(file);
        // rest of code
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // rest of code
    }
}
```

Before I try to call the service in a new thread, code above works fine. But, when I try to call the service in a new thread, like below code, it says java.io.FileNotFoundException (The system cannot find the file specified), and the main problem is in this line `fos.write(file.getBytes());`. Here is how I create the new Thread in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "uploadfile")
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestParam (value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    try {

        // ...other process

        // ================================== code below not work
        Thread create;

        create = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    service.create(file);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        create.start();

        // ================================== code below not work
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    service.create(file);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();

        // ================================== code below not work
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                service.create(file);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }){{start();}};

        // ...rest of code
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ...rest of code
    }
}
```

above is several way how I try to make the thread but none of them works, result with same execption.

Objective: In short, I want to make the file reading in background and immediately send response to client after the service called.

Comment: you should use something like t1.join() to wait the convert finish. but that works in an sync way  too, no needs background threads.

Comment: @exudong yes I've tried using t1.join() but it doesn't work in the background. It means the system will wait until the thread finish then continue the prcoess.

Comment: that's the way since you require "immediately send response to client ".  another way is  the regiser a callback function to the background task, when the background tasks finsihed, it invoke the callback to send response to the client. but looks your current framework not support.

Comment: @exudong then, what framework that could support it? So I could find and learn about it.

Comment: you can study tomcat 8 https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/java/faster-websites-using-asynchronous-processing-tomcat-8/

Comment: @exudong thanks a lot for ur recomendation. For anyone else who thinks that my usecase could solve without using another framework, please help me. Any information will be appreciated!

Comment: sorry it's not strict I said "not support", spring support too.

Answer (score 0):

Spring supports async way by return a Callable object. the pseudo code is like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "uploadfile")
public Callable<ResponseEntity<?>> create(@RequestParam (value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    return () -> {
     try {
            service.create(file);
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.error( /*some error*/
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
}
```

Here's a tutorial reference : https://niels.nu/blog/2016/spring-async-rest.html .

another reference: [How to make a async rest with Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473215/how-to-make-a-async-rest-with-spring)